# Position of a point with fixed distance between other two points

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I have two points, $p_1$ and $p_2$, in a cartesian plane, and a fixed radius, $r$.

I want to find the coordinates of another point, $p_3$, that is in the same line of the $p_1$ and $p_2$, and always in a fixed distance, $r$, from the point $p_1$.

$(a,b)$       $(?,?)$                      $\quad \quad \quad\space(c,d)$
 
$p_1$---------$p_3$---------------------$p_2$

        $\quad r$

Considering that the points $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be on anywhere in the plane.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is the problem of finding the  point $p_3$$ (x,y)$ that divides
>   the the joint of two points $p_1 (a,b)$ and $p_2 (c,d)$ internally in
>   the ratio $r:t\normalsize$ (i.e. $p_1p_3:p_3p_1 = r:t$)

First you have to find the value of the consequent of the ratio i.e $t$, for that  find the distance of $p_1p_2$ using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Geometry) distance formula and then subtract $r$ from it.

Thus, $$ t = \left(\sqrt{  (c - a)^2 + (d-b)^2 } \right) -r  $$

Now you can find $$ x= \frac{rc + ta}{r+t}$$ and $$ y=\frac{rd + tb}{r+t}$$

Comment: The denominator should be just $t$

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the down vote now...plz edit your post :)

Comment: @Swapan: Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean
$$
p_1+r\frac{p_2-p_1}{|p_2-p_1|}
$$
**Afterthought:**

If you're not worried about being on the line segment between $p_1$ and $p_2$, then
$$
p_1-r\frac{p_2-p_1}{|p_2-p_1|}
$$
works also.

Comment: This is on the line between $p_1$ and $p_2$ as long as $|p_2-p_1|\ge r$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's define point $P_3$ as $P_3(e,f)$ .

You may calculate coordinates $e$ and $f$ using following equalities :

$e=\frac{a+\lambda c}{1+\lambda}$ , and $f= \frac{b+\lambda d}{1+\lambda}$

where $\lambda=\frac{r}{|P_1P_2|-r}$ , and $|P_1P_2|=\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure $P_3$ lies inside the segment $P_1P_2$? This means $r\le \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$. In this case the point $P_3$ is given by $$\left(\frac{a \times (\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}-r)+c \times r }{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}},\frac{b \times (\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}-r)+d \times r}{\sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}}\right)$$

Comment: are you sure about the denominator?

Comment: @MaX You may wish to edit your answer once more to correct present $t$ to $t-r$, or to put the denominator as just $t$ :)

Comment: @MaX No problem....but please be patient, I never argue (and sometime bet) without being sure that "If you can prove me false, it will imply 0=1" :D