# Position of a point$\ \ C(x|y)\ \ $ on a line between $\ \ A(1|1)\ \ $ and $\ \ B(5|2)\ \ $ when $x (i.e. 1)$ away from $A$

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

How to calculate the position of a point on a line when the start end endpoint of the line and the distance of the point from the start are given$?$

Example:

$A(1|1)$

$B(5|2)$

Distance of point $C$ from $A = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the incorrect answer I hastily wrote before.

Since the line passes through (1, 1) and (5, 2) and $C = (x, y)$ also lies on that line, AC has the same slope as AB.

So, $$\frac{y - 1}{x - 1} = \frac{2 - 1}{5 - 1} = \frac{1}{4}$$
$$x-1 = 4y - 4$$
$$x = 4y - 3$$

Now, $$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$$ 
Since distance of C from A is 1.

Substituting x = 4y - 3 $$(4y-4)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$$
$$=17y^2 - 34y + 16 = 0$$

This has solutions, $y = 1.2425$ which gives $x = 1.97$ and another solution which does not lie between A and B.

So $C = (1.97, 1.2425)$

Comment: Thanks @SilverSlash, I think the equation should be 17x^2-40x+32. (x|y) of C are not given. I found another equal question here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85580/position-of-a-point-with-fixed-distance-between-other-two-points?rq=1

Comment: Could you explain why we need to substitute y= (1/4)x. Also, (1.84198285,  0.460495) is NOT a point on AB.

Comment: I have redone it.